# Paperclip uploads on Heroku using S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm sorry to rehash an old gripe but I'm at my wits end and not sure where to go next. I am using Paperclip on Heroku and have S3 uploads configured. I was able to get things working in my local development environment but once it's running on Heroku I run into this error:

```
AWS::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect (The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

I've googled this error and read through the Heroku documentation and I believe I have everything set up correctly. I initially thought that my problems stemmed from having my bucket in the `s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com` region, but I'm not convinced anymore.

Here are the relevant parts of my Heroku config:

```
AWS_REGION:                      us-west-1
S3_BUCKET_NAME:                  my-super-awesomely-amazing-bucket
```

From my config/environments/production.rb file:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    } 
  }
```

My paperclip.rb initialize file:

```
if Rails.env.production? 
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
end
```

And my paperclip config from the relevant model:

```
has_attached_file :document,
:styles => { },
:default_url => "/image_styles/:style/missing.png"
```

So...what am I doing wrong here? At this point I'm sure I've missed something obvious but I'm stumped on where to go from here. I feel like I've assiduously configured everything and yet that `PermanentRedirect` error keeps coming up.

Answer (score 3):

**Bucket**

This might not be the direct solution, but we've found that you have to include the `bucket` option *outside* of your `s3_credentials` block:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

This is working 100% for us on Heroku, but whether it wil work for you (as your bucket is in a different region) is a different matter

If you need more help, ask a comment and I'll gladly give you some ideas

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it turns out it was something completely different. My problem was that I had created a bucket in the N. Cali region. Don't ask me why, but that was the issue. When I changed it to a bucket created in Oregon, things started working. Pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://adamthedeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/02/awss3permanentredirect-bucket-you-are.html . Previously this happened to Europe region buckets only and get resolved by setting `AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST`. Hope this solve your issue.